# How to install GrinderStone 2.5.5 in Eclipse Mars, forbidden access to grinderstone.googlecode

Tags: eclipse, google-code, grinder

I have tried to install Grinderstone 2.5.5 through Eclipse MarketPlace. During the installation process I was prompt to enter username and password for googlecode project. I have the appropriate google account but obviously that account does not have access to Grinderstone project. So I got Error forbidden access.

This are the links I am trying to access:

http://grinderstone.googlecode.com/svn/update/site.xml

https://code.google.com/p/grinderstone/downloads/list

Is it possible to get access to Grinderstone SVN project site? And how to get access if it is possible?

Or alternatively is it possible to download GrinderStone 2.5.5 in some other way?

(I didn't find jar for offline installation)

Comment: Google Code shut down earlier this year, so you won't get anywhere with that. Have you tried https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/grinderstone ?

Comment: Plugin mentioned on the link downloads Grinderstone from the same link as a mentioned above, so the behaviour is the same. Quote: "No repository found at http://grinderstone.googlecode.com/svn/update/site.xml."

Comment: If they're not maintaining their code repository and distribution channel properly, you have to start looking for a replacement; it may be abandoned.

Comment: Thank you for the response, most probably you hit the spot